# Error with sockets.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, sockets

I have this error with sockets.js :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M3VEuNw net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in my socketCoonection
```

**socket.js**

```
exports.connectSocket = (io) => {
        socket.on('send-message', (message) => {
        messageService.sendMessage(message, (response) => {
            console.log('socket message sending', message);
            socket.to(message.reciverId).emit('recive-message', message);
        });

    });
 }
```

Here I have written all the backend socket.io code.

**config.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import socketConnection from '../util/conn.socket';
class Config {
   constructor() {
       this.app = express();
       this.socket = socket;
       this.http = http.Server(this.app);
       this.io = this.socket.listen(this.http);
     }
  }
 listen(port) {
    this.http.listen(port, () => {
        log.info(`Server started: http://localhost:${port}/`);
    });
}
```

In my client side, I am using angular.

**socket.service.ts**

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 import { Message } from './interfaces/message';
 import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

 const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/') ; 
 @Injectable()
 export class SocketService {
    constructor() {
      }
   socketConnection() {}
     // for sending a message
     sendMessage(message: Message) {
      socket.on(message.receiverId).emit('send-message', message);
      //console.log(message);
     }
    reciveMessages(message) {
       socket.emit('recive-message', message);
         console.log('message is recived' + message);

    }

 }
```

Error : zone.js:2975 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M3V4EsN net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
It seems this error is occurring at the time when server sending data to the client.In socket 'send-message', message is printing in the console, but after some time this error is occurring.I have installed socket.io-client and imported CDN also in my index.html.